# Modify coffeelint rule on code by comment

Tags: coffeescript, lint, coffeelint

Is it possible to add some comment to ignore or modify coffeeling rules on a certain block (indented)?

I use the rule for max 80 columns on script, but I have some string values for a objetc that surpasses that value, and break the lines will make the code worse to read.

Ex.:

```
##
# @coffeelint ignore max_line_length
##
object:
  attr: "some/huge/line/string/with/embed/#{values}.that/surpasses/the/max/column/width"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the syntax for that.

```
 # coffeelint: disable=max_line_length
 object:
   attr: "some/huge/line/string/with/embed/#{values}.that/surpasses/the/max/column/width"
 # coffeelint: enable=max_line_length
```

Comment: Thanks!  Helped me out too